# sql to find out stats from user login log table

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc, ado, adodb

I have a vb application which communicates with a mysql database.
When users log in, this creates a new row in a "LoginLog" table.

For example:

```
id      user           datein             lastactive        dateout     computer
1       brian          2013-01-01 12:11   NULL              NULL        br-Office
```

When brian closes the application, some code will look for the last brian entry with null as dateout and br-Office as the computer, and update the row with `dateout=Now()`.

('Computer' matters because users can log in from one PC, abandon it without logging off, and then log in using a different PC, so it is important to separate the instances.)

'Last active' is not used at the moment I am going to have it store the time of last activity performed by the user, so I can find out if a user has not been active for, say, 5 minutes or more.

I would like to know what SQL I could use within the application to find out a list of users currently online. I could just search for distinct users who have null dateout, however some users just shut their PC off, or they will get a crash, so the dateout time is not captured. I would therefore like a limit, e.g. dateout null, but where datein is less than 24 hours ago.

I would also like to be able to find out the most ever users online at one time with some SQL in the application. I will point out that I have no way of using `Set @variable;` effectively as the application can only execute one statement at a time via ADO/ODBC. If I run statements separately, variables are not remembered from one statement to the next. I have to run select statements to return values to assign as variables in the application, and the application's variable used to form the next query. I cannot execute stored procedures via the application either. So would it possibly be bruteforce of select statements?

Comment: get rid of the semicolon and you should be able to use set @variable.

Comment: if you follow `set @variable = 0` with the word ` select` that immediately flags as invalid syntax in workbench, and of course returns an error if you actually submit e.g. `set @varhg = '1' select * from loginlog;`

Answer (score 0):

To get the users online, you need to know the last row for each user.  Then you just need to apply logic:

```
select
from LoginLog ll
where datein >= now() - interval 1 day and
      id = (select id
            from LoginLog ll2
            where ll2.user = ll.user and
                  ll2.computer = ll.computer
            order by datein desc
            limit 1
           ) and
      dateout is not null;
```